# Hazelcast exception in logging

Tags: hazelcast

Using:
Hazelcast 3.6.1
Log4j 2.5
slf4j 1.7.13

Hazelcast client using Log4j cannot log the Membership 'printout'

```
Member [localhost]:19325
```

This client is being initialized programmatically (not via spring).

Instead, exception is thrown by logging infrastructure

`2016-03-09 15:49:34,195 hz.client_0_qv-core.event-4 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender STDOUT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: 
    Member [localhost]:19325`

```
at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1429)
at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479)
at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:362)
at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:840)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFormatMessage.formatMessage(MessageFormatMessage.java:94)
```

The error isn't related to the number of cluster members.

Server is able to print the message just fine using the same codebase.
I can provide the full stack trace if needed.

Comment: An important note:
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
This is being used to direct to log4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining logging configuration with system property: -Dhazelcast.logging.type solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind Hazelcast logging directly to log4j?
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#logging-configuration

Comment: I've tried all combinations:
clientConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j"); , slf4j, jdk default. As long as I am redirecting the log to any logging framework ontop of log4j, i get this exception.

Comment: Woah, ok, so adding in jvm system property like -Dhazelcast.logging.type worked, setting in client config did not?

Comment: Good question, can you file a github issue for that, I guess it should work as well, thanks.